# Apache Pig , programe run issue 

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

```
REGISTER /home/hadoop/pigg/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;

-- Use the PigStorage function to load the excite log file into the raw bag as an array of records.
-- Input: (user,time,query) 
A = LOAD 'hadoop-test-data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user: chararray, site: chararray, view: int, click: int);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.UPPER(user);
-- Use the PigStorage function to store the results. 
STORE B INTO 'test-pig-result' USING PigStorage();
```

This is my code , i am just converting my username fielded in uppercase.I have stored this code in test.pig in pig root folder.

I am running this code with ,

```
java -cp $PIGGDIR/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/conf org.apache.pig.piggybank test.pig
```

But its keep throwing following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pig/piggybank/Main
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.piggybank.Main
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Could not find the main class: org.apache.pig.piggybank.Main.  Program will exit.
```

But if I run same program on grunt then it gives me proper output.
I have tried every possible param of **java -cp**'s second last param.

And i also need an example , in which **CSVLoader** class is used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run pig locally you should run `pig.jar` not `piggybank.jar`
the piggybank.jar will be included in the script by the `REGISTER` command in the script

Comment: Or just use the `pig` executable in `bin`.